# How do I disable website suggestions from searchguide.tds.net?

Tags: dns, domain-name

Whenever I misspell a website name into my web browser, I get a "website suggestions" page from my ISP (TDS Telecom).   I find this site-finder "service" very annoying.   How can I configure my computer to get rid of it?

For example, here is what it look like when I type "no.site" into my URL bar in Firefox:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens because TDS has configured their DNS servers to never respond that a host is unknown.   Instead, they direct all unknown sites to an IP address that redirects to their search guide.   Here is a query from their DNS server showing that:

```
$ dig @216.165.129.158 no.site
;; ANSWER SECTION:
no.site.        10  IN  A   198.105.254.19
```

#### Solution 1: Disable searchguide.tds.net itself in your hosts file

You can put a bogus IP address in your computer's local hosts file (`/etc/hosts` or `hosts.txt`) file.   That prevents your web browser from ever being able to connect to the page that shows the search results:

```
192.168.0.0 searchguide.tds.net
```

The downside is that bad hosts still redirect to the search guide URL and the browser will try to connect until a timeout.

#### Solution 2: Change the DNS servers for your computer

Instead of using the TDS DNS servers, you can configure your computer to use other DNS servers.   Google runs DNS servers on 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.   Google has [instructions](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) for changing your settings to use them on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

#### Solution 3: Change the DNS servers for your home network

The router from TDS has a setting [in its configuration interface](http://192.168.0.1/) for changing the DNS servers for your entire home network.   You can put the Google DNS servers in under **Advanced Setup** -> **IP Address**  -> **LAN IP Settings** -> **Set the DNS values**.   You can statically assign 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Unfortunately, this will break the search functionality on your cable box.  The cable box relies on "internal" DNS entries that are available through TDS DNS servers.

#### Solution 4: Run a proxy DNS server to filter it out

I run dnsmasq DNS server on my computer with the TDS dns servers upstream.   dnsmasq has a setting for filtering out bad replies for no such domain in `dnsmasq.conf`:

```
# TDS site finder
bogus-nxdomain=198.105.254.19
```

I configured my home network to use my local server with the filter.  Then sites behave as expected, and my cable box is still happy.